# Class Constructor and Get Design

Tags: c#, class, constructor, data-access

When designing a class and the constructors I have a question regarding getting a record.

In an example if I have a car class

```
public Car
{
    ...
}
```

I have the option of creating a constructor that could get a certain instance of a car for example:

```
public Car(int carID)
{
    //Get car from database
}
```

Or I could write a public method to get the car:

```
public Car GetCarByID(int carID)
{
    //Get car from database
}
```

Is there a preferred (best practice) method for getting an instance of a class?  The code seems to read cleaner to do get an instance of an object:

```
Car MyCar = new Car(5);
```

vs.

```
Car MyCar = new Car();
MyCar.GetCarByID(5);
```

Comment: In this instance i would have a class called car that handles all the basic info. (Like the id). I would then have a class called CarCollection which holds are cars in a collection. In this class i would have the GetCarById method. In that method i would search through the collection of cars and return the car with that id. This question is very opinion based though as it is it is off topic for here.

Comment: Separation of concerns, if your `car` class really is a class that holds information about a `car`, you should be using a Data Access Layer to construct `car` objects, not requiring the `car` to know about the database.

Comment: Why should a car know how to get itself from the database ? Neither of your proposals is good and is a violation of SRP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend separating your database access from your domain model classes like Car.

This can be done by putting all database access retrieval operations in their own set of classes. These are referred to as repositories. There are different approaches for making these repositories. It depends on how your data is stored in the database and whether you use entity framework. Some prefer generic repositories whereas others don't like this generic approach at all. But the bottom line is that the repositories are taking care of accessing the database for object retrieval and for storing. It should not be done by the domain object ie Car itself because it should have only operations that belong to the Car and what make it a Car object. Storing the Car in the database is not something a Car should know how to do.

An example of using the repository pattern can be found here : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688929/Repository-Pattern-and-Unit-of

There is also a nice article on MSDN about the repository pattern :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Bottom line is to use the repository for your database access. It is used for loading and storing data from the database and provides an extra abstraction layer. If needed you can create an interface for every repository which will allow you to do unit testing as well.

Far better than creating methods in your classes that don't belong there.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Although this brings up another question, if I had a DriveCar() method that needed to access the cars max speed from the database, I think the DriveCar() method would belong in the class definition, would it then call the car repository class to get the max speed?  Or am I thinking about this in all the wrong way?

Comment: The moment the Car repository retrieves the data that belongs to the car, it should retrieve all aspects about the car that are important and what makes a car a car. The max speed is clearly an attribute of the car so yes it should be retrieved directly when you load the car form the Db. You can go even further in this direction by doing domain driven design and using only an aggregate root for the entry points. But this is a different topic. http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=97p2

Answer (score 2):

As I have said in my comment I would do this to manage the cars and allow loading of a car by id or anything else you want to load it by.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Car() { }
    public Car(int id) { Id = id; }
}

public class CarCollection
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public void AddCar(Car car) { Cars.Add(car); }

    public Car GetById(int id) { return Cars.Single(x => x.Id == id); }

    public CarCollection(List<Car> cars) { Cars = cars; }
    public CarCollection(Car car) { Cars = new List<Car>() { car }; }
}
```

Comment: I like this example, however the implementation seems to require a lot of overhead.  For example to get a car by Id, I first have to instantiate a Car object, then instantiate a CarCollection object to populate the Car object? Some of the other examples use static classes, but from my reading it sounds like static classes shouldn't be used in this fashion?

Comment: I don't see how this uses a lot of overhead as you would need to store all the cars in a list / array / dictionary / other data structure anyways. The collection allows easy access to the cars that you want without writing static methods. In those static methods you would have to pass a collection of cars into them for them to be able to iterate over the cars and select the one/s needed. The class above already handles that. As an example if you ever used a DataGridView you will also note that this is like the RowCollection and ColumnCollection classes.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use a [static method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx), like so:

```
public static Car GetById(int carId)
{
    ... Load car and return it ...
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Car myCar = Car.GetById(18);
```

Comment: A car should definitely not be extended with methods like these. It violates SRP and will be hard to unit test.

Comment: Oh, it really depends. For a small project adding such a static method can save you the time without costing you anything. Which is why I said this was one solution, and a simple one at that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to address the comments about separation of concerns, I'd suggest the following:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make {get; set;}
    public string Model {get; set;}
    // additional properties here.
}

public static class CarFactory
{
    public static Car CreateCar(string modelId)
    {
        Car car = new Car();
        // Load the car via whatever mechanism you wish;
        // e.g., web service, database, etc.
        return car;
}

Car fordFairlane = CarFactory.CreateCar("57fordFairlane");
```

This keeps the code for creating a car object separate from the car object itself, and allows you to change how a car is created without ever touching the car class.

Comment: This does not offer an easy way to load a car by the id. This simply creates a new car with an id.

Comment: The loading code isn't really important, so I didn't put a lot of extraneous DB code.  The important thing about the example is that it highlights how to keep the code that creates the object out of the object's class code itself.  Hence the comments after the call to the constructor.

Comment: No, the comment states clearly that you can get the car loaded from the database. Add a way of storing to this so called 'factory' and what you have is a repository.